# Change of the fontsize when saving an svg from matplotlib

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, inkscape

i have some data that i visualize with matplotlib. The font i use is Arial and the font size should be 10. I save the diagram as svg to postprocess it in inkscape. Everything is smooth up to the point that the font size of axes ticks, labels etc. is 12,5 instead of 10. Below is the code where i define the rcParams:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = ['sans-serif']
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial']
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False

mpl.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'

do some stuff: fig, plt.plot, etc.

fig.savefig('fig.svg',dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True)
```

There should be deffinitely a better than to resize everything in inkscape:)

Comment: This smells like a bug.  Can you put in code for a _minimal_ example?  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: I would think the issue probably lies in the fact the matplotlib is treating a number like "10" as 10pt. 10pt and 12.5px in a browser equate to about the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of Inkscape: it *always* measures font sizes in pixels (and not points). The factor 1.25 in font sizes arises from the fact that inkscape uses 90 pixels/inch and the fontsizes you specify in points in matplotlib assume 72 points/inch.

Further reading: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5964

**However**, if you save the svg to pdf in inkscape (after postprocessing) you get the same font sizes as the following example shows:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = ['sans-serif']
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial']
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
mpl.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,1))
for pos,ts in enumerate(range(8,16)):
    plt.text(pos,0.5,ts, fontsize=ts)
plt.plot([-1,pos+1],[0.5,0.5])
plt.gca().yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_visible(False)

# save as svg and pdf
plt.title('svg')
fig.savefig('figure.svg',dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True)
plt.title('pdf')
fig.savefig('figure.pdf',dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight',transparent=True)

# use inkscape to convert svg to pdf
os.system("inkscape --export-area-page --export-dpi=300 " \
        "--export-pdf=figure2.pdf -f=figure.svg")

# concatenate pdfs for comparison and make png
os.system("pdfnup --nup 1x2 -o output.pdf figure.pdf figure2.pdf")
os.system("convert -density 300 output.pdf output.png")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot)) just to be sure. according to the post, you gave the link to, there was no option in inkscape to set the fontsize to be displayed in pt like in other software. As far as i get, it is still the case. Right?

Comment: No, unfortunately this option does not exist (at least up to version 0.48.3.1 which I am using).